# Custom Java sort by name

Tags: java, sorting, collections, compare, compareto

I want to sort something like this:

Given an ArrayList of objects with name Strings, I am trying to write the `compareTo` function such that `Special T` is always first, `Special R` is always second, `Special C` is always third, and then everything else is just alphabetical:

```
Special T
Special R
Special C
Aaron
Alan
Bob
Dave
Ron
Tom
```

Is there a standard way of writing this kind of compare function without needing to iterate over all possible combinations between the special cases and then invoking `return getName().compareTo(otherObject).getName());` if it's a non-special case?

Comment: Do you have Guava by any chance?

Comment: Have you tried? Show us what you got so far.

Comment: `list.sort(Comparator.<String>comparingInt(Arrays.asList("Special C", "Special R", "Special T")::indexOf).reversed().thenComparing(String::compareTo));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the special cases in a `HashMap<String, Integer>` with the name as key and position as value.  The advantages are:

1. search is in O(1) order of magnitude
2. The HashMap may be populated from an external source

Comment: How can I initialize a hashmap as a static part of the class?

Comment: in a [Static Initialization Block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), like any other static variable